# Instance Storage Missing in EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I took an c1.xlarge instance in EC2(Ubuntu 12.04) which promised me 1690 Gigs of instance storage. But when I checked the instance, I could only find 450 Gigs of it. What am I overlooking and where?

Comment: this should rather be asked from Amazon support

Comment: just wanted to know whether anyone here had similar experience

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some instances, there is a special block device mapping necessary to mount every available instance storage space. Here is [a link to a description](http://ubuntu-smoser.blogspot.de/2011/02/getting-ephemeral-devices-on-ebs-images.html) on how to mount the extra space so that it also becomes available in your instance.

Answer (score 4):

try **cat /proc/partitions**  command and check if it is attached to your instance. There might be a case where EBS storage is not mounted on your instance however it would be available as attached storage. If you can see 1690 Gigs with above command, you have to mount remaining storage to your instance then only it would be available to your instance for usage and can be seen through df -kh command.